# Error al insertar datos a mysql con foreach

Tags: php, mysql

El siguiente codigo lo uso para insertar a mysql con un foreach

```
foreach ($puntosVisita as $nombre) {
    echo $nombre;
    mysqli_query($bd, "INSERT INTO puntosVisita (idRuta, nombre, fechaMod) VALUES ('$consecutivo', '$nombre', '$fechaMod')") or die(mysqli_error($bd));
}
```

solo me registra el primer valor del array en la base de datos, el problema es que los guarda con id = 0 , como puedo solucionarlo?, adjunto imagen de los campos de la base

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dejáme ver si entiendo, el id es el problema al no ir incrementando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola si te esta guardando el ID de valor 0 es porque no tienes definido el auto incrementado de tu llave solo tienes que definir lo con el mismo phpmyadmin te dejo el Ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder exactamente el error era que no lo tenia definido como auto_increment